# SQL "for XML" and built-in functions like "comment()"

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm writing an SQL select statement which returns XML. I wanted to put in some comments and found a post asking how to do this. The answer seemed to be the "comment()" function/keyword. So, my code looks broadly like this:

```sql
select  ' extracted on tuesday ' as 'comment()',
        (select top 5 id from MyTable for xml path(''),type)
for xml path('stuff')
```

...which returns XML as follows:

```xml
<stuff>
  <!-- extracted on tuesday -->
  <id>0DAD4B42-CED6-4A68-AB7D-0003E4C127CC</id>
  <id>24BD0E5F-8B76-43FF-AEEA-0008AA911ADD</id>
  <id>AAFF5BB0-BFFB-4584-BACC-0009684A1593</id>
  <id>0581AF24-8C30-408C-9A48-000A488133AC</id>
  <id>01E2306D-296A-4FF7-9263-000EEFF42230</id>
</stuff>
```

In the process of trying to find out more about "comment()", I discovered "data()" as well.

```sql
select top 5 id as 'data()' from MyTable for xml path('')
```

Unfortunately, the names make searching for information on these functions very difficult.

Can someone point me at the documentation on their usage, as well as any other similar functions ?

Thanks,

**Edit:**

Another would appear to be "processing-instruction(blah)".

Example:

```sql
select  'type="text/css" href="style.css"' as 'processing-instruction(xml-stylesheet)',
        (select top 5 id from MyTable for xml path(''),type)
for xml path('stuff')
```

Results:

```
<stuff>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
  <id>0DAD4B42-CED6-4A68-AB7D-0003E4C127CC</id>
  <id>24BD0E5F-8B76-43FF-AEEA-0008AA911ADD</id>
  <id>AAFF5BB0-BFFB-4584-BACC-0009684A1593</id>
  <id>0581AF24-8C30-408C-9A48-000A488133AC</id>
  <id>01E2306D-296A-4FF7-9263-000EEFF42230</id>
</stuff>
```

Comment: [`data()` is briefly described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510419.aspx). You may also find [the XPath 1.0 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) useful, though `comment()` is only mentioned in passing.

Comment: (As an aside, I would recommend using `[square brackets]` to capture aliases. Using `'single quotes'` is deprecated in some scenarios, and really makes those look like string delimiters.)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I think, in searching for "comment()", I found that TechNet article - which is where I found "data()".

Comment: A little more information here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2011/12/15/for-xml-path-using-node-tests-in-column-aliases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to the BOL info: [Columns with the Name of an XPath Node Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522573%28v=sql.120%29.aspx%20%22columns%20with).
This details the functionality you are interested in. (It can indeed be a pain to find)

Also you can find quick functional examples [here](http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/xml-path-column-alias-functions)

Comment: Hi, That first link seems broken (to me), but the second is really useful - but is the same article as the sqlservercentral one I listed. Thanks anyway. A TechNet example lies here :- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522573.aspx

Comment: [fixed link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522573.aspx) Sorry about that.